# How to hide the DOM-element at the left of the <body> without horizontal scrollbar will appear?

Tags: jquery, html

Consider below `jQuery` [script](https://jqbook.net.ru/file.php?id=151&iframe=1):

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow"); 
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

(source: [jqbook](https://jqbook.net.ru/jquery/Effects))

[image]

This script allows to move the square to the left and to the right by buttons.
If we move the square out of `<body>` to left, the horizontal scrollbar will not appear, however it will even if we define `width` for `body` and move the square to the **right** of the body canvas.

Could I move the DOM element to the right of the body without the horizontal scrollbar will appears?

Note: this problem is actually for hamburger-menu. No problem if to hide it at the left of body([simple example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579936/htmljavascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) in Russian but you need code only), but how to hide the menu in the right of the body without scrollbar will appears?

Comment: jsut add a css rule overflow hidden to the body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do it. You can just simply add a CSS rule.

```
body{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the simple solution!